Well known multidimensional recurrence relations/sequences
I'm using ML to approximate multidimensional recurrence relations, and am wondering where there are any well known or commonly used multidimensional recurrence relations.
E.g. for a 3D array where every data point is a 2x2 grid, it would look something like this:
$$x_{0, 0, t}=x_{0,0,t-1}\times x_{0,1,t-2}$$
And so on and so forth for $x_{0,1,t},x_{1,0,t},$ and $x_{1,1,t}$.
Thanks in advance.

Is Autoregressive_model you're looking for your described vector time series autoregression purpose? You can simply view your 2 by 2 grid data point at each time step as a vector tuple of length 4.

Yes I will be flattening the data but I need some data to flatten first

What do you mean "I need some data to flatten first"? Of course any ML training needs training/test splitted data first, thus you need the flattened data before choosing a ML model implicitly. So you confirmed autoregressive model is the answer for your question?

no, I am looking for a dataset - I already have a model that works with really simple recurrence relations like xt-1_0 = xt-2_1 * 2, I am just looking for more well known ones
